# Get array indices after filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a js array like this:

```
let weekdays = [                                        
  ["monday"],
  ["tuesday",37800,72000], // numbers are opening/closing time in seconds from midnight
  ["wednesday",36000,50400],
  ["thursday",36000,50400],
  ["friday",36000,57600],
  ["saturday",36000,64800],
  ["sunday",36000,64800]
];
```

I want to be able to get the item that matches today's day.

I was using

```
const d = new Date();
const n = d.getDay();
const day = weekdays[n];
```

but was finding that with the data coming out of the CMS that sometimes days were missed out or in the wrong order which was messing that up.

So I thought it would be more accurate to filter the array and get the item where `weekdays[0]` matched today's day, e.g.

```
let dayName = d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {weekday: 'long'});
dayName = dayName.toLowerCase();
const day = weekdays.filter(weekday => weekday[0] == dayName);
```

But I can no longer access the start and end times with `day[1]` and `day[2]` as I was before.

I've read about using `map` or `reduce` but can't get my head around what that needs to look like for my case.

Could someone help, please?

Comment: `filter` returns an array of items passing the callback, not the found item

Answer (score -1):

```js
let weekdays = [                                        
  ["monday"],
  ["tuesday",37800,72000], 
  ["wednesday",36000,50400],
  ["thursday",36000,50400],
  ["friday",36000,57600],
  ["saturday",36000,64800],
  ["sunday",36000,64800]
];
const d = new Date();
const n = d.getDay();

let dayName = d.toLocaleString('en-GB', {weekday: 'long'});
dayName = dayName.toLowerCase();
// if weekdays has unique dayName
const day = weekdays.reduce( (res, weekday) => (weekday[0] == dayName) ? [...weekday] : res, []);
console.log(day, day[0], day[1], day[2])

// if not unique
let weekdays1 = [                                        
  ["monday"],
  ["tuesday",37800,72000], 
  ["tuesday",37801,72001], 
  ["wednesday",36000,50400],
  ["thursday",36000,50400],
  ["friday",36000,57600],
  ["saturday",36000,64800],
  ["sunday",36000,64800]
];

const days = weekdays1.filter( weekday => weekday[0] == dayName);
console.log(days)
```